# How do I make the game sound volume go up

Tags: javascript, html, audio

Sound function-

```
function sound(src) {
            this.sound = document.createElement("audio");
            this.sound.src = src;
            this.sound.setAttribute("preload", "auto");
            this.sound.setAttribute("controls", "none");
            this.sound.style.display = "none";
            document.body.appendChild(this.sound);
            this.play = function(){
                this.sound.play();
            }
            this.stop = function(){
                this.sound.pause();
            }    
        }
```

putting sounds in-

```
flying = new sound("flying.wav");
```

rendering sounds-

```
flying.play()
```

what i'm wondering is, is there anyway to make the volume of the wav go up?

Answer (score -1):

You just interact with the [`volume` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/volume) of the `audio` element.

Here's an example function from a file that I use that gives the user an up and down button to adjust the volume by `.1` in either direction and makes sure that they don't wind up setting it to an out of bounds value. It's pretty self-explanatory.

```
function adjustVolume(increment) {
  // Get the proposed new volume level and check that it
  // is between 0 and 1 (inclusive) or you will throw an error.
  var proposedV = audioElement.volume + increment;
  if (proposedV >= 0 && proposedV <= 1) {
    audioElement.volume = proposedV;
  }
}
```

Comment: `audioElement.volume = Math.min(Math.max(audioElement.volume + increment, 0), 1);`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Sure, but optimized code comes ***after*** working code. And, the way I have it is easier for newbies to read and understand.

Comment: It's not about the optimization, it's about functionality. If the `volume === 0.9` and `increment === 0.2` you don't want to cancel the change, you want to set it to `1`

Comment: What is audioElement because when i try it out it says its not defined, what would i put it as?

Comment: @ScottMarcus actually your solution with `proposedV >= 0 && proposedV <= 1` only applies the change if `proposedV` is valid, while the solution provided by @PatrickRoberts applies the closest valid value if proposedV isn't valid

Comment: @PatrickRoberts If you read my post, I mentioned that my code is connected to buttons that alter the volume by `.1`. I also mentioned it was just an example.

Comment: @Matthew `audoElement` is a variable that references the `<audio>` element in the code. You have to change that to match your variable.

Comment: @Olian04 Yes. Read my post and my comment to Patrick Roberts. I clearly state that the increment is pre-set to .1.

Comment: A down vote? Really? Was it for pointing out the right API, or was it for adding a link to reference. Or, was it for proving sample code?